# Highcharts Stacked column drill down not working?> How to set drill down series for my scenario?

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

I have created 5 different series on different conditions for stacked column high chart with drill down. Stacked column is showing up but drilldown is not working.

```
       $.each(brands, function (name, y) {
            brandsData1.push({
                name: name,
                y: y,
                drilldown: versions[name] ? name : null
            });
        });
        $.each(versions, function (key, value) {
            drilldownSeries1.push({
                name: key,
                id: key,
                data: value
            });
        });

        $.each(brands, function (name, y) {
            brandsData2.push({
                name: name,
                y: y,
                drilldown: versions[name] ? name : null
            });
        });
        $.each(versions, function (key, value) {
            drilldownSeries2.push({
                name: key,
                id: key,
                data: value
            });
        });

            $.each(brands, function (name, y) {
            brandsData3.push({
                name: name,
                y: y,
                drilldown: versions[name] ? name : null
            });
        });
        $.each(versions, function (key, value) {
            drilldownSeries3.push({
                name: key,
                id: key,
                data: value
            });
        });
            $.each(brands, function (name, y) {
            brandsData4.push({
                name: name,
                y: y,
                drilldown: versions[name] ? name : null
            });
        });
        $.each(versions, function (key, value) {
            drilldownSeries4.push({
                name: key,
                id: key,
                data: value
            });
        });
            $.each(brands, function (name, y) {
            brandsData5.push({
                name: name,
                y: y,
                drilldown: versions[name] ? name : null
            });
        });
        $.each(versions, function (key, value) {
            drilldownSeries5.push({
                name: key,
                id: key,
                data: value
            });
        });
```

on Highchart:

```
               series: [{
                            name: 'Brand1',
                            data: brandsData1
                        }, {
                            name: 'Brand2',
                            data: brandsData2
                        }, {
                            name: 'Brand3',
                            data: brandsData3
                        }, {
                            name: 'Brand4',
                            data: brandsData4
                        }, {
                            name: 'Brand5',
                            data: brandsData5
                        }
                        ]
```

How to set Drilldown series here?

Comment: Can you please add JSFiddle of your code?

Comment: Sorry this was a sample, my code was in the same condition, but it reads all the values from the database...

Comment: You can use some static data, just for demo purposes. Anyway, to use drilldown you need to set [`drilldown.series`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown.series).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for stacked columns with drilldown:

http://jsfiddle.net/8zfcsssu

You can make the drilldown dynamic by using something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "your service which returns json",
    success: function(data) {
        drilldowns = data;
        series = drilldowns[e.point.name];
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
setTimeout(function () {
    chart.hideLoading();
    chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories([]);
}, 1000);
```

if you add this to the drilldown event handler of the jsfiddle example, it will work OK.

Hope this helps

Peter